# How can I create a Gujarati Supported Language Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, key, android-service, android-keypad

I want to create a keyboard in Gujarati (Indian languages) that its work like android default English keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use [KeyboardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html)

[Here](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html) is a sample project for a soft keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But here sample project is used button in xml . but i want to developed Keyboard using Keyboard Tag